# Why is *int different from []int in go

Tags: c++, arrays, go, pointers, memory

I worked with `C` and `C++` for a while before starting to learn go, and I'm curious why `*int` and `[]int` are treated as different types in golang.  Whether you want to think of it as an array or not is up to you, but they should both be pointers to some location in memory indicating the beginning of a list of type int.  That list may very well be of size one, but my point is, why are `[]int` and `*int` not the same thing in go?

Comment: Note that pointers and arrays aren't the same thing in C nor C++ either.

Comment: Understand that `[]int` is **not** an array; it's a *slice*. `[4]int` is an array, `[100]int32` is an array; `[99]bottles` is an array; they are all fixed size.  `*int` points to **one** value. Go is not C or C++. Try this: https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro  and this https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types and this https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#arrays

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `[]int` has three values internally: pointer to backing array, length of backing array and capacity of backing array.  The Go runtime ensures that the application does index outside the bounds of the backing array.

An `*int` is just a pointer as in C. Because Go does not have pointer arithmetic (outside of the [unsafe](https://godoc.org/unsafe) package), a `*int` cannot be used like an array as in C.

Comment: The fact that pointer arithmetic is forbidden is the (or a) key reason that Go needs something like slices.  C's pointer arithmetic is the (or a) key reason that C doesn't—but experience proves that people shoot themselves in the foot with pointer arithmetic. :-)

Comment: "An []int has three values internally" This is an implementation detail.

Comment: @Volker The specification states that a slice has an associated backing array, length and capacity.  You can quibble about whether "associated" implies "pointer to",  but that's the only sensible implementation.

Comment: It is the only sensible implementation but it is an implementation detail nevertheless.